# Calculating a reflected arc

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, math

I am using the following code to calculate points for a circle arc drawn with a Line Renderer.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= pts; i++)
{
    float x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float y = center.y + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    arcLine.positionCount = i + 1;
    arcLine.SetPosition(i, new Vector2(x, y));
    ang += (float)totalAngle / pts;
}
```

How can I change the angle `ang` to create a reflected arc along the line `P1P2` as in the image below?

Please note that `totalAngle` represents the portion of the circle that is to be drawn between 0 and 360.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that's possible, but I've come up with another way that works like this:

First, a helper function:

```c#
Vector2 GetPosition (float radius, float angle)
{
    angle *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    return new Vector2
    {
        x = radius * Mathf.Cos(angle),
        y = radius * Mathf.Sin(angle)
    };
}
```

Then, compute positions `p1` and `p2`:

```c#
var p1 = GetPosition(radius, ang);
var p2 = GetPosition(radius, totalAngle);
```

To derive the mid-point `p3`:

```c#
var p3 = (p1 + p2) * 0.5f;
```

And finally rotate the original point about `p3` to obtain the reflected point:

```c#
var pos = p3 * 2f - GetPosition(radius, ang);
```

And that's it! Your code should look something like this:

```c#
void Draw ()
{    
    var p1 = GetPosition(radius, ang);
    var p2 = GetPosition(radius, totalAngle);
    var p3 = (p1 + p2) * 0.5f;

    for (int i = 0; i <= pts; i++)
    {           
        var pos = p3 * 2f - GetPosition(radius, ang);       

        arcLine.positionCount = i + 1;
        arcLine.SetPosition(i, center + pos);
        ang += totalAngle / pts;
    }
}

Vector2 GetPosition (float radius, float angle)
{
    angle *= Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    return new Vector2
    {
        x = radius * Mathf.Cos(angle),
        y = radius * Mathf.Sin(angle)
    };
}
```

Here's it in action:

[image]